# How to make my client receive more than 1 response from server for every one request sent?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking

I am learning to write a Python client.  It needs to be able to keep receiving responses of the `current status of the request queue` from the server when my client requests it. The server stops sending the status of the request queue when the client sends an off command.

Besides that, the client needs to have a prompt, `<enter command>`, printed out to the terminal so a new request can be sent to the server when a user enter a new command/request.

I was using `select` to make the client non-blocking. So the client can keep getting responses from the server while it is ready to read a user's command and send to the server.  However, I wasn't able to control when the prompt, `<enter command>`, shows up. It ends up being displayed in the middle of the receiving of the multiple messages displaying the status of the request queue from the server.

Should my client use a blocking or non-blocking socket for the situation?  Anything I missed?  Thanks!